# VMware bridged network, guest adapters down after state restore

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, docker

Running Ubuntu guest inside a Windows 10 machine using VMware `16.1.2`

Main issue is that after saving and restoring state, none of the docker container's are accessible anymore and their networking not functional.

Before saving the state, there are multiple docker containers running with default network configurations (by default they are bridged). Additionally the guest to host is using bridged network as well:[image]

I found that after restoring the state one of the networks goes in a `DOWN` state:

Before (`$ ip addr`):

```
42: br-621e12990280: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:52:96:09:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.0.1/16 brd 172.25.255.255 scope global br-621e12990280
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:52ff:fe96:9ab/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

After:

```
39: br-2da2dcaa6043: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c4:2b:0a:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

That is the only change, note that the reason for names changing is that in order to bring it back up, I do a `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` which re-creates it. However the main problems seems to be that the network keeps going down after restoring state. I used virtualbox before converting this machine to VMware and this issue did not exist

Any suggestions on what could be killing guest networks during save/restore state procedure and how to stop it?